# Como utilizar state em uma função?

Tags: react-native

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      xsemana: '0',
      meses: '1',
      minutos: '1',
    };
  }

  calcula(){
    const total = this.state.xsemana *
    (52 * this.state.meses / 12) *
    this.state.minutos;
    alert(total);
  }

  render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Vezes por semana</Text>
    <TextInput style={styles.input} keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({xsemana: text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),})} value={this.state.xsemana} />

    <Text>Quantos meses?</Text>
    <TextInput style={styles.input} keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({meses: text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),})} value={this.state.meses} />

    <Text>Quantos minutos?</Text>
    <TextInput style={styles.input} keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({minutos: text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),})} value={this.state.minutos} />

    <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
      <Button title="Calcular" color="#417ee0" style={{height:80}} onPress={this.calcula}/>
    </View>

  </View>
  );
}
}
```

Quero fazer um cálculo na função `calcula()`, utilizando os valores dos `state` acima.

Porém, estou recebendo o erro:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.xsemana')

Como utilizar na minha função, os estados criados acima?

Comment: Quando você chama essa função ?

Comment: @wmsouza coloquei o código completo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve fazer um **bind** do método `calcula()`, para poder utilizar o `this` dentro dele.

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      xsemana: '0',
      meses: '1',
      minutos: '1',
    };
    this.calcula = this.calcula.bind(this);
}
...
```

#### Leitura recomendada:

- [Por quê é necessário usar bind quando se trabalha com ES6 e ReactJS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127171)

Comment: vou testar. voce pode explicar pra que serve o bind?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo editei a resposta e coloquei uma pergunta feita aqui no **SOpt**